# CloudFormation to automate creation of a new EC2 instance & volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to do the following actions in sequence and wondering if I should use CloudFormation to achieve this:

Launch a new EC2 instance (currently I'm manually doing it by selecting "Launch more like these" on a specific instance.

- Stop the new instance.
- Detach the volume from the new instance.
- Create a new volume from a previously created snapshot.
- Attached that newly created volume to the new EC2 instance created in step 1.
- Restart the EC2 instance.

If this can't be done via CloudFormation would it be possible to automate it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take Johns advice and use an AMI. This sample will get you started, it launches a single EC2 using an AMI (latest patched one) in an Auto Scale Group of Min 1 - Max 1 so one EC2 instance will always be on regardless of a power failure, AZ going down, etc.

Replace XYZ with your products name:

```
Parameters:
  KeyPairName:
    Description: >-
      Mandatory. Enter a Public/private key pair. If you do not have one in this region,
      please create it before continuing
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
  EnvType:
    Description: Environment Name
    Default: dev
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:  [dev, test, prod]
  Subnet1ID:
    Description: 'ID of the subnet 1 for auto scaling group into'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  Subnet2ID:
    Description: 'ID of the subnet 2 for auto scaling group'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  Subnet3ID:
    Description: 'ID of the subnet 3 for auto scaling group'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'

Resources:
  XYZMainLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
  SSHMetricFilter:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::MetricFilter'
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Ref XYZMainLogGroup
      FilterPattern: ON FROM USER PWD
      MetricTransformations:
        - MetricName: SSHCommandCount
          MetricValue: 1
          MetricNamespace: !Join
            - /
            - - AWSQuickStart
              - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
  XYZAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref XYZLaunchConfiguration
      AutoScalingGroupName:  !Join
            - '.'
            - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
              - 'ASG'
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref Subnet1ID
        - !Ref Subnet2ID
        - !Ref Subnet3ID
      MinSize: 1
      MaxSize: 1
      Cooldown: '300'
      DesiredCapacity: 1
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'The Name'
          PropagateAtLaunch: 'true'
  XYZLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'false'
      PlacementTenancy: default
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPairName
      ImageId: ami-123432164a1b23da1
      IamInstanceProfile: "BaseInstanceProfile"
      InstanceType: t2.small

      SecurityGroups:
        - Fn::If: [CreateDevResources, !Ref DevSecurityGroup, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are wanting to launch an Amazon EC2 instance with the boot disk coming from an Amazon EBS Snapshot.

Might I suggest a simpler process?

Rather than creating a Snapshot of the Amazon EBS volume, instead **create an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of the original instance**. Then, when launching the new Amazon EC2 instance, simply select the AMI. This will result in a new instance starting up with the desired boot disk.

Alternatively, you can **create an AMI from an existing Amazon EBS Snapshot** by selecting the Snapshot and choosing the `Create Image` command. (But I think this only works for Linux, not Windows.) Then, launch new EC2 instances from the AMI.

Behind-the-scenes, an AMI is actually just an Amazon EBS Snapshot with some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can automated all these tasks using [SSM Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html).

Specifically, your **SSM Automation** can consist of the following documents/actions:

- AWS-AttachEBSVolume
- AWS-DetachEBSVolume
- AWS-StopEC2Instance
- AWS-StartEC2Instance
- AWS-RestartEC2Instance

Your SSM Automation can be **triggered by CloudWatch Events**. Also the SSM Automation can be constructed using CloudFormation.